# Getting problem while submitting manuscript

Tags: miktex

I have submitted a manuscript, I used miktex to compile my pdf and sent that pdf, but I was then asked to submit Tex file. I never did that before, can anyone please tell me , is it fine to send the Tex file only or should I share all the pdf files I attatched for images in that pdf along with the Tex file?

Comment: Probably an off-topic question but I would say it is normal/common to send your text file to a publisher.

Comment: I believe you should interpret the publisher's request as comprising not only the main "driver" file (called, say, `main.tex`(, but also all subsidiary files. These would include the image files used in the paper's figures and one or more .bib files (in case you used an external program, such as bibtex or biber, to help create the formatted bibliography) If `main.tex` has `\input` and/or `\include` directives, you should also provide the associated .tex files. And, if you've written your own LaTeX package files (with extension .sty), you should provide those as well.

Comment: you should give everything they need to typeset the document so usually a zip archive of all the tex, images bib files, etc

Comment: Many publishers want to make sure that their document matches their style and fits with other inputs, which might require some tweaking of the submissions. For my sins for some years I was Editor-in-Chief of the IEEE Computer Graphics magazine. If a submitted article was too short then the next one had to begin immediately afterwards without a gap of perhaps one and a half empty columns in the published magazine. Publishers may wish to change the format of your submission without changing the text.